# Draw funnel chart in Vega/ Vega-lite

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana, vega, vega-lite

I'm using vega in kibana for visualizing data. Now I want to draw a funnel chart but it doesn't have any examples of this. [image]
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a funnel chart in Vega-Lite using a bar chart with `stack: "center"`. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAAoCWADobgwHaFmQDCA9u2L5cieAwGQANFH7528MgEYALAAZ1qgL6Sq1WoxZtO3OgCc+xFgGMF03nzkLUigEwatO6jXrNWHLqiQAIr4eAwAZgyE0FIyDvJK7h66GPq+RgFQAHKEAOZ8Ygji7LH2jmQAHO7aKd4GfsaBZgUFAJ4spbIJqABs1Z5eaYb+3Dy4Fhy5nfFOYGoaNV5oPsONUADqEnZds24LA3orDZmQAGIcYQBe0dPlztUpALpUi1CE7FZ80JNktK2-kHg7RO7D4AFsLrhSpFWDEmukRnZiHxTLN2MJcJpXpBcLBWoRTGRKHpalAwbBTABrbgAIwpUlJkHen2+7CmqHQSygn3GhI5gOB3FBEPYeGhUVwcKg9QypVweXeUvRuExBy8kAAHgCgR1AgBHULyBiiBhYLh2GGS0YzUrERBWamBKzveAEyCaUke6ivGiM8lU7iujW2RnMr4-flB2a0S1SsoJOw6k4G2BGk1m91ejBZx4DSAAdwY0HgAAsyABWdQgTRAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Pipeline": "Consultation", "Count": 140000},
      {"Pipeline": "Prospect", "Count": 120000},
      {"Pipeline": "Qualified", "Count": 100000},
      {"Pipeline": "Negotiation", "Count": 80000},
      {"Pipeline": "Prototype", "Count": 60000},
      {"Pipeline": "Closing", "Count": 40000},
      {"Pipeline": "Won", "Count": 20000},
      {"Pipeline": "Finalized", "Count": 10000}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {"y": {"field": "Pipeline", "type": "nominal", "sort": null}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "Pipeline", "type": "nominal", "legend": null},
        "x": {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "center"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ],
  "width": 500
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using vega lite v2.6 when I applied your code, my chart isn't in the center like this.

Comment: Vega-Lite 2.6 is two major releases and two years behind the current release (4.4). I would suggest upgrading to a newer Vega-Lite; this will fix your issue.

Comment: thank you, but I use vega lite in kibana, it's so difficult to update

Comment: do you have any ideas for this

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible in Vega-Lite 2.6 - I stick by my original suggestion.